# GDB's "info sharedlibrary" shows same "from" and "to" address for all libraries

Tags: gdb, shared-libraries

I have a driver that loads a shared library, and in the library there is a segfault in the ISR. I can get the address of the segfault and I'm trying to get some context as to where that segfault is. However, the address lies outside of the address space of the loaded libraries (it's at `0x79something`).

What interested me was that it looks like all the libraries have a size of zero - what would be causing this? It then would make sense that anything that happens in those libraries is a segfault, it's outside of the valid address space for the program.

```
0x0000000078000000  0x0000000078000000  No          libnanospin.so
0x0000000078011000  0x0000000078023040  Yes         libstrings.so.1
0x0000000001000000  0x0000000001000000  No          libc.so.4
0x0000000078024000  0x0000000078024000  No          my_library.so
0x000000007804a000  0x000000007804a000  No          libnvxhci.so
0x000000007805f000  0x000000007805f000  No          libnvclock.so
0x0000000078075000  0x0000000078075000  No          libnvdma32.so
0x0000000078086000  0x0000000078086000  No          libnvdtcommon.so
```